# JPanel Containts inside JFrame

Tags: swing

I am Having a JTextField in JFrame having mouselistener on it,and i want to display JPanel with some contents when mouse event is fired.JPanel is displaying but the contents in it are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot write text directly inside `JPanel`. Use a `JLabel` and put the text inside that `JLabel` and then place the JLabel on the `JPanel`

Comment: i have written text in that manner only still it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `revalidate()` after adding new panel, which will instruct the layout manager to recalculate the layout and `panel.repaint();` if necessary.

If this didn't solve your problem, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)